# How does RStudio find R GUI on your desktop

Tags: r, production-environment

Can someone help me understand how does RStudio find the R GUI to run during an RStudio session?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: RStudio *is* a GUI.  It runs base R code using the methods described here:  https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Linking-GUIs-and-other-front_002dends-to-R .  Depending on the OS, it uses various methods to find R, e.g. the PATH, the Windows registry, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`RStudio` requires a previous `R` installation to run. When you install `RStudio`, the following window shows up so you can select the `R` installation you want to use:

[image]

Additionally, you can change the `R` installation used by `RStudio` under `Tools -> Global Options -> General Tab -> R Version field`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful.